# What is the meaning of "as classic as they come"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> These shoes are as classic as they come.

I am not sure if it means that its style won't be affected whether the trend changes as time goes. Does it mean that this item is a timeless piece?

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the phrase *as classic as **they** come*, which implies that this is a quintessential case.

Comment: Have you looked up the word "classic" in a dictionary? Let us know what you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*noun* is as *adjective* as they come" is an expression meaning that "*noun* is extremely *adjective*".

It's a way to indicate emphasis that stands out more than just saying 'very'.  Depending on the situation, it can be as strong as "There is nothing more *adjective* than *noun*."

> He is as smart as they come = He is extremely smart.
>
> Your car is as junky as they come = Your car is extremely junky.

So your example could be read as:

> Those shoes are very classic.
>
> There are no shoes more classic than those.

or even as

> I've never seen shoes as classic as those.

As to the use of the word '[classic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classic)' in referring to apparel, see definition 1c (MW)

> characterized by simple tailored lines in fashion year after year